# Renting a car in Minsk, Belarus for EU citizens

Tags: car-rentals, driving-licenses, belarus, minsk

I am from European Union. I have driving license and IDP (international driving permit) both issued in Denmark.

I am considering using latest Belarus visa cancellation for EU citizens, fly to Minsk airport, get a 5-days tourist visa and rent a car. Should all that be doable?

Comment: Why do you need a visa since it's going to be visa free?

Comment: Perfectly doable.

Comment: A little remark which is important though may sound off-topic: 5-day visa-free mode doesn't mean a free 5-day visa - there is no visa at all. Immigration is like anywhere in Europe for you - just the in and out stamps. A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the usual car-hire conditions (Sixt for example requires a licence held for a minimum of one year) but with a passport, IDP and EU citizenship then the [new rules](http://www.belarus.by/en/press-center/press-release/five-day-visa-free-regime-to-enter-into-force-in-belarus-on-12-february-2017_i_51265.html) brought in today allow what you would like.